# JRuby App's with Java libraries need to access Database

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

I have a JRuby on Rails app. Postgres is the database.  I have a simple jar (java library) that is included and its accessible inside my JRuby app. Now this simple jar needs to query and modify the database. Can this be done?

Do I basically open a JDBC connection directly to the database. Any examples/pointers is super helpful.

Sorry I don't have any code for this question. I am looking for advice on how to access the application's db via java in my JRuby App.

Comment: JAR isn't your. Right? In this case just establish connection to DB as recommended in documentation for this JAR.

Answer (score 0):

When I think "Rails" I think activerecord.  There is an activerecord jdbc postgres sql adapter gem.

https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter/versions/1.3.15

The readme on github shows you how to layout the connection information in a yml file and then make a connection:

https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter